# How to close dropdown menu on anchor click without reloading page

Tags: javascript, html

Good day, I am very new to JS and I have a drop-down menu that drops upon clicking the hamburger and closes when clicking the close button. However, if you click the anchor link on the same page the dropdown is not close, it will just go to the anchor section. I need help with modifying the JS so that when the anchor link is clicked the dropdown menu will hide and the hamburger will toggle.

```js
var hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
        var menu = document.getElementById('navbar--middle');
        menu.style.display = "none";
        hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
          this.classList.toggle("change");
          if (menu.style.display === "none") {
            menu.style.display = "block";
          } else {
            menu.style.display = "none";
          }
})
```

```css
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-nav .nav-contents {
        font-size: 40px;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

.navbar--middle {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #dedede;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 55px;
    height: 35%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  
  .hamburger {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    right: 5%;
    top: 3%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid green;
  }
  
  .icon1 {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  
  .icon2 {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  
  .icon3 {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  
  
  /* Rotate first bar */
  
  .change .icon1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 4px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 4px);
  }
  
  /* Fade out the second bar */
  
  .change .icon2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  
  /* Rotate last bar */
  
  .change .icon3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -5px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -5px);
  }

  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .center-logo-below-menu .logo, .logo {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar--middle navbar-hide" id="navbar--middle">
    <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
        
<div class="nav-contents"><a class="about" href="#about-us">About us</a></div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>

        <div class="navbar--right">
        <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
        <div class="icon1"></div>
        <div class="icon2"></div>
        <div class="icon3"></div>
    </div>
  
  <p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <h2>
  <a name="about-us"></a>About Us
  </h2>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this below your js code:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-contents > a');
anchors.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menu.style.display = "none";
        hamburger.classList.toggle("change");
    });
});
```

We found all anchors in .nav-contents and put it to the variable 'anchors'. For each anchor we added a new event listener which changes style of the menu. Trigger of the event in our case is 'click'.

Hope this help! Regards,

Comment: Thank you, the drop down menu is closing but the hamburger menu still remain on close icon instead of changing back to menu icon.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You need to add hamburger.classList.toggle("change");